# why we cannot pass boolean value as props in React , it always demands string to be passed in my code

Tags: reactjs, redux

Even though I have applied propType validation, my editor throws an error on when passing boolean value for the `hasvacancy` prop. Here is what I'm seeing:

> Error:
>   'SyntaxError: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text'

I know I am passing a string type value for 'hasvacancy' prop but what do I need to do so I can pass a boolean or other data types via the prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


class VacancySign extends React.Component{

  render() {
    console.log('------------hasvacancy------', this.props.hasvacancy);
    if(this.props.hasvacancy) {
      return(
        <div>
          <p>Vacancy</p>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return(
        <div>
          <p>No-Vacancy</p>
        </div>);
    }

  }
}

VacancySign.propTypes ={
  hasvacancy: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

render(<VacancySign hasvacancy='false'/> , 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: <VacancySign hasvacancy={false} />

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You should enclose the boolean value in {}:

```
render(<VacancySign hasvacancy={false}/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: And the same rule goes when we pass integer or float value . RIght ??

Comment: @VishnuShekhawat anything wrapped in `"` or `'` would be sent as a string. If you want to keep the value type, such as an integer, float, boolean, object, etc, you would need to wrap it in `{}`.

Comment: returns `Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `static`.` for me

Comment: I think it's better to set defaultProp 'hasvacancy' as false and just set the property like <VacancySign hasvacancy />

Answer (score 45):

I'm updating this answer, as my original one (omitting the value) is no longer considered best practice. Now, simply wrap your value in curly braces, as you would any other Component attribute value. So, instead of this (this still works):

```
render(<VacancySign hasVacancy />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Do this:

```
render(<VacancySign hasVacancy={true} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

If you're using the former syntax, make sure to update your propTypes to make hasVacancy not required; otherwise, you are free to restrict it with `isRequired`:

```
VacancySign.propTypes ={
    hasVacancy: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}
```

Comment: This short form is much more concise

Comment: This shows a warning in console: ```warning.js?6327:33 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `editable`.```

Comment: @Tom It looks like your PropType is incorrectly set. The error message is saying you're receiving a boolean value (good) for a non-boolean attribute "editable" (bad). Make sure your PropType is React.PropTypes.bool, and not React.PropTypes.string, or something else.

Comment: @Artif3x it's been a while but I remember that in my case either `editable` is a html attribute of a native component like `textarea`, or I had not set prop types at all (in which case it shouldn't be a string either, right?)

Comment: @Tom The "editable" attribute is of type String, not Boolean. Remember, "editable" can be "true", "false" or "inherit", so assigning it a boolean value will be invalid. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable

Comment: This answer shows an alternative way of passing boolean props values, but it doesn't explain when/why it should be preferred. "Don't try to pass Boolean values as attribute values" Why? Also: what if the boolean value is dynamic?

Comment: Furthermore, what if the declared default value of `hasVacancy` is true?

Comment: This is _not_ what the React official docs recommends: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true

Answer (score 10):

To those of you who received the warning

```
warning.js?6327:33 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `editable`
```

This happens if you pass the props down without taking the boolean values out
of the props.

E.g.:

```
const X = props => props.editable ? <input { ...props } /> : <div { ...props } />
```

This can be circumvented by

```
const X = ({ editable, ...props }) => editable ? <input { ...props } /> : <div { ...props } />
```

Comment: This is the real answer. You can also change true = +true or make true to a numerical value because JS is awesome but not taking the value out of props really gives this error. Thanks for explanation!