# Passing props to unrelated component comes back undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-proptypes

I have the following structure:

- Folder 1

  - Subfolder 1

    - File.jsx
- Folder 2

  - Subfolder 2

    - Subfolder 2

      - File.jsx

When passing a boolean as props from the file of Folder 1 to the file in Folder 2, I get undefined. My component from folder 2 is imported in folder 1, so it should work. Any ideas without using Redux will be highly appreciated.

Component from Folder 1:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useAppContext } from 'fusion:context';
import Image from '../../image/default';
import './style.scss';

const Headline = () => {
  const appContext = useAppContext();
  const { globalContent } = appContext;

  return (
    <div className="article-headline text-align">
      <div className="article-headline-body">
        <h3>{globalContent.headlines.basic}</h3>
      </div>
      <Image isFeatured />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Headline;
```

Component from Folder 2:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './default.scss';

const Image = ({ src, global, isFeatured }) => {
  // console.log(global);


  console.log('is featured', isFeatured);

  /* some unrelated code */


}

Image.propTypes = {
  src: PropTypes.any,
  global: PropTypes.any,
  isFeatured: PropTypes.any,
};

export default Image;
```

Comment: `<Image isFeatured />` should be setting `isFeatured` to true surely?

Comment: Even when I pass a variable that's set to true it's still undefined in Folder 2. I read an article somewhere that for booleans you don't really have to set it to true when passing it since it's automatically true.

Comment: It's not "undefined in 'Folder 2'", it's undefined in the component. The location of a component's source does not matter (assuming all imports are correct, which it seems like they are). Are the other parameters working? Does it work without `proptypes` being set? There's no particular reason it shouldn't work, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/39326300/438992

Comment: Everything else is working as it should. I tried passing this.props.isFeatured as well, still undefined.

Comment: When console logging the props, isFeatured doesn't exist even. It's not reaching the unrelated component.

Answer (score 1):

PropTypes.any will return undefined instead of false both in javascript will goes to false but you could set a default value or set PropTypes.any to PropTypes.boolean instead

Comment: I tried setting a default value and converting prop types to the boolean, the same result.

Comment: sorry it was suppose to be ```PropTypes.bool```

Comment: Yes, I know it's bool, but still, the issue persists unfortunately, I'm out of options.

Comment: When console logging the props, isFeatured doesn't exist even. It's not reaching the unrelated component.