# Does `this.props` always return a truthy value when passed to component state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean, jsx, conditional-operator

I want to pass props to my react component and have a function where I toggle the font weight of a span between bold and normal.

My React component:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <FontChooser min='4' max='40' size='16' text='Fun with React!' bold='false'/>
   </div>,
document.getElementById('container'))
;
```

And I am trying to pass the `bold = 'false'` prop to the initial state of the component like this:

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        hidden: true,
        bold: this.props.bold,
        size: 16 
    }
    }
```

And then I have the function

```
toggleBold() {
        this.setState ({
            bold: !this.state.bold
        });
    }
```

And it should render:

```
render() {
        var weight = this.state.bold ? 'bold':'normal';

    return(
           <div>
           <input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" onChange={this.toggleBold.bind(this)}
           <span id="textSpan" style ={{fontWeight: weight, fontSize: this.state.size }}>. 
                 {this.props.text}</span>
           </div>
```

My problem is that `this.props.bold` should return false but the ternary operator executes 'bold' which should only be executed if `this.props.bold` is true. It seems like it is treating `this.props.bold` as a truthy value rather than falsy, even though it is set to false in the component property.

So does `this.props` always return a truthy value when we pass it to component sate? Even if it is set to 'false' in the component prop definition?

Comment: You're passing `false` as a string rather than as an actual false value, your JSX should look like `<FontChooser min='4' max='40' size='16' text='Fun with React!' bold={false}/>` Since 'false' is a non-empty string, it is truthy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are boolean props used in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60816731/how-are-boolean-props-used-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `bold` prop as a string and since the value passed is not an empty string, the `this.state.bold` is being evaluated as `true` in the ternary.

```
<FontChooser min='4' max='40' size='16' text='Fun with React!' bold='false'/>
                                                                    ^
```

```js
let bold = 'false'

console.log(!!bold)
```

**Solution**, Pass value for `bold` as a boolean instead.

```
<FontChooser min='4' max='40' size='16' text='Fun with React!' bold={false}/>
```