# Syncfusion Date Range Picker

Tags: syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I am trying to prevent the user to edit the input text area by typing, allowing only changes made with the pop up calendar....
I followed the documentation but the property allowEdit is not working on my code

```
<DateRangePickerComponent
      cssClass="customCSS"          
      placeholder="Select date range"
      allowEdit= "false"
      onChange={this.dateRangeHandler}
    />
```

I am also finding not so easy to style this Date Picker...is inheriting all the style from his parent component so I need to customise every single bit of it...

Answer (score 0):

We need to define the allowEdit property with correct JSX syntax in the react platform to get rid of the reported issue.

```
<DateRangePickerComponent
cssClass="customCSS"
placeholder="Select date range"
allowEdit={false}
onChange={this.dateRangeHandler}
/>
```

**Sample**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6jwtbf

[image]

Please refer the below documentation to know more about this.

[How are boolean props used in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60816731/how-are-boolean-props-used-in-react)

https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html