# React Bootstrap unasigned xml variable?

Tags: javascript, react-bootstrap

Hi I have 2 questions: **First,** in React bootstrap there is often used Xml like variable, but it has no value:

```
            <Bs.Modal
            show={this.state.isVisible}
            // onHide={this.props.onHide}
            scrollable={true}
            size="lg"
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            centered></Bs.Modal>
```

In this case its  last attribute **centered** and I would like to ask how is this "undefined" variable called. And **second** question is, how to make this variable switchable, like {isCenteredtype && center}

Comment: It's a boolean property. It can be set like any other property.

Comment: Yes, if it's simply present it means it defaults to `true`. And for the second question, you can set it "dynamically" using `centered={<some-boolean-expression>}`

Comment: thanks guys @tromgy and Dave Newton, its working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are boolean props used in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60816731/how-are-boolean-props-used-in-react)